# How to check Google Api quota from my application?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I have an application, which use a youtoube-data-API for analyze some data in videos description.And i want to check my quota usage in time from my app.

Answer (score 0):

Below I'm assuming you're referring to a GCP API. If so:

#### Cloud Quotas product

After years, it's finally possible to list, view and even change GCP quota preferences programmatically.

The product you're searching for is [Cloud Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quotas/overview). It is in relatively early days, with version 0.1.0 released in January 2024 and 0.5.0 in March 2024 (see [version history](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-cloudquotas/latest/history)).

Because of that, only Java client seems to be supported for the time being and you'll find some dead links in the documentation.

To use the API you'll need couple of things:

1. Enable the [Cloud Quotas API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudquotas.googleapis.com/quotas)
2. Read the [guides](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quotas/overview) to understand the concepts and what the product offers.
3. Head over to [Cloud Quotas API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-cloudquotas/latest/overview) to find coordinates of the Java client. You'll find that the link to the samples is broken. This is [the right link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/main/java-cloudquotas/samples/snippets/generated/com/google/api/cloudquotas/v1/cloudquotas) at the time of writing.
4. Head over to [Cloud Quotas Client Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-cloudquotas/latest/com.google.api.cloudquotas.v1.CloudQuotasClient) for documentation of available operations of the Java client.

#### Note

In [GCP IAM Quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) you'll find quotas for various services, e.g. `retail.googleapis.com/bq_import_operations`. When interacting with the Client to query or change quotas, you'll have to provide a `QuotaInfoName` built like so:

```
QuotaInfoName.ofProjectLocationServiceQuotaInfoName(
    "[PROJECT]", "[LOCATION]", "[SERVICE]", "[QUOTA_INFO]")
```

The important thing is that `retail.googleapis.com` is the `[SERVICE]` above, but `bq_import_operations` is the so called "metric name" and **not** the `[QUOTA_INFO]` above. In this example the correct `[QUOTA_INFO]` is `BigQueryImportsPerProject` (pointing to the metric `retail.googleapis.com/bq_import_operations`).

You can request a list of all quota infos from the client for a particular service like so (snippet in Kotlin):

```kotlin
CloudQuotasClient.create().use { cloudQuotasClient ->
  val serviceName = ServiceName.of(
    ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId(),
    "global",
    "retail.googleapis.com"
  )
  val quotaInfos = cloudQuotasClient.listQuotaInfos(serviceName).iterateAll().toList()
  println("Quota infos: $quotaInfos")
}
```

which will output multiple entries like this one:

```
name: "projects/xxx/locations/global/services/retail.googleapis.com/quotaInfos/BigQueryImportsPerProject"
quota_id: "BigQueryImportsPerProject"
metric: "retail.googleapis.com/bq_import_operations"
service: "retail.googleapis.com"
is_precise: true
container_type: PROJECT
metric_display_name: "Number of pending BigQuery import long running operations"
quota_increase_eligibility {
  is_eligible: true
}
dimensions_infos {
  details {
    value: 100
  }
  applicable_locations: "global"
}
service_request_quota_uri: "https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas"
```

Having the list, search for an entry having `metric` property set to the name as seen in [GCP IAM Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas). You'll find `[QUOTA_INFO]` (needed for construction of the `QuotaInfoName`) in the `quota_id` of the same entry.

Answer (score -4):

You can check your quota from the google console by going to 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en

To monitor API traffic from your Google Developers console:

Go to the Google Developers Console and sign in as a G Suite super administrator.
From the Project list, select the project you're using for the migration.
On the left, click APIs & auth > APIs.
On the Enabled APIs tab, click the API you want to monitor.
The Usage tab shows how many requests are being made over time.
The Quotas tab shows the daily quota you have remaining. 
To increase the quota for an API, you can apply using the Apply for higher quota link on the Quotas tab. Applying for increased quota doesn't guarantee approval, which can take some time to process.

Hope that helps.